# StartCoroutine with IEnumerator including Time.deltaTime sometimes infinite loops

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, timedelta

I'm hoping someone can help me with the issue I'm having creating my 2D game. I'm using Unity to create an Android application. I'm moving my character (a goat) across the screen using a grid system (GridMove - http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/GridMove).

I included the Global and Move script in the following links :

Global : http://codeshare.io/i6BDn

Move : http://codeshare.io/JHDAs

In the move Update function there is a StartCoroutine which moves the goat to a certain position (based on the grid size which is 0.5).

The transform.position gets set with a Vector3.Lerp and the Time.deltaTime. On my computer it works fine, but when I start opening programs or attach the debugger the goat seems to keep looping in the same position. This also happens on a low end phone or even an Samsung Galaxy s4.

Is there a way to stop the goat from resetting his transform.position or a way to check it? I can't seem to pinpoint where it goes wrong.

[image]

Looping goat position :
[image]

If you need more information, just let me know.

Comment: Please include your actual code in the question, and not a code share link.

Comment: Do you really need that "yield return 0;" in "move" method?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (t <= 1f)
```

Lets think about this for a second. You want to move him from position `0f` to position `1f`. If he reaches `1f`, the code **will not stop running** because the condition of `position == 1f` still satisfies the `while` loop condition.

instead it should be like this:

```
float threshold = Single.Epsilon;
while ((1f - t) > threshold)
```

Bigger problem:

```
//Done with moving, set bool to false to "release" the update function
t = 0;
isMoving = false;
yield return 0;
```

**Do not** end your `Ienumerator` with a `yield return 0`. It does the exact same thing as `yield return null`, and will loop the `IEnumerator` all over again. You just reset your variables as well so it will start all over from position `0f`. Instead you should end the `IEnumerator` by just terminating the code. It will not loop over again:

```
//Done with moving, set bool to false to "release" the update function
t = 0;
isMoving = false;
```

Comment: Going to try this out, thank you. Will commnent my findings in here also and mark it if it's resolved

Comment: I'm sorry.. The issue keeps happening even with the changes you suggested. Here is the new Move file :http://codeshare.io/5kem6

Comment: hmm, seems like it should work, but theres a couple things i would change. First of all, i would include the fact that a movement is happening in the `if` block for the `StartCoroutine` as such: `if (tempPauseTime <= 0 && !isMoving)` this way, even if pausing is up, it will still wait for all movement to finish before running it again.

Comment: Another thing is you shouldn't be adding or subtracting by a constant every frame. This is because render frames don't execute in exact intervals, so changing a value by a constant like this every frame `tempPauseTime -= 0.01f;` will prove to be very choppy. Instead it should be like this: `tempPauseTime -= Time.deltaTime * decreaseSpeed;`

Comment: Can you provide the exact code? Or am i doing this right?

`tempPauseTime -= (Time.deltaTime * 0.01f);` with 
`if (tempPauseTime <= 0 && !isMoving)` then `StartCoroutine(move(transform));` and `tempPauseTime = pauseTime;`

Comment: yes it seems alright to me, though your timer speed of `0.01f` seems a little low, `deltaTime` gives you the amount in seconds it took the frame to render from last frame, so if you are running on 30 frames per second, `deltaTime` should be averaging at about `0.033f` and if you multiply that by your speed, `0.01f`, then you are averaging subtracting `0.00033f` from your timer each frame. I would suggest using a public variable for your speed which you can adjust during runtime until you get the best results.

Comment: Thanks! I changes `0.01f` to `0.3f`and it seems to be running smootly. Sadly on the mobile device this bug keeps happening... I can't get my finger on the problem but it seems that slow devices (sometimes my computer too) lets the character loop infinitely on the same spot.